# Override registration decorator for Aurelia container in Jasmine test

Tags: jasmine, aurelia

We have a component that is registered as a transient service in the Aurelia DI container using a decorator, like this:

```
@transient()
export class EntityGraphObserver {
    ...
}
```

So that whenever it is injected, it is a new instance.

However when used in Jasmine specs, we want to override this default registration by passing a spy which is registered as an instance, so that we can mock the component, but it never works - the instance received by the test is always a new instance of the real component, not the spy, for example:

```
import { Container, Aurelia } from "aurelia-framework";
import { bootstrap } from "aurelia-bootstrapper";
import { StageComponent, ComponentTester } from "aurelia-testing";
import { Bootstrapper } from "...";
import { EntityGraphObserver } from "...";

describe("shareholder-step", () => {
    let component: ComponentTester;
    let observer: any;
    let container: Container;

    beforeEach(() => {
        observer = jasmine.createSpyObj("EntityGraphObserver", ["attach"]);

        component = StageComponent
            .withResources("modules/business-details/shareholder-step")
            .inView("<shareholder-step></shareholder-step>");

        component.bootstrap((aurelia: Aurelia) => {
            Bootstrapper.configure(aurelia);
            container = aurelia.container;
            container.registerInstance(EntityGraphObserver, observer);                                            
        });
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        component.dispose();
    });

    it("initializes with shareholder data", async done => {
        // arrange / act
        await component.create(bootstrap);
        const vm = component.viewModel as ShareholderStep;
        await vm.activate(...); // some activation data

        // assert       
        expect(vm.shareholders.length).toBe(1);
        expect(observer.attach).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); // NEVER WORKS

        done();
    });
};
```

It looks like the transient decorator always overrides the registration we specify when bootstrapping the component for testing, which stops us from being able to isolate components with decorators.

The child container injected into the component is not available during the bootstrap phase, but I suspect that's where the transient registration is occurring, however I would expect it to only use that as the default registration where there is no existing registration in the container hierarchy, so maybe it's a bug in the Aurelia framework.

Is there a way to control the container setup so that registrations from decorators can be ignored or overridden, or is this a bug?